# NXLog and old Windows events

Tags: windows, events, elasticsearch, syslog, nxlog

It is possible to configure NXLog to send old Windows event so Syslog (ELK)?

So, if my machine is offline (any reason to lose network) I want to know what is happened in offline mode. Maybe someone attack my machine, or whatever, and I want to get all that log events in Syslog.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

NXLog has flow-control, this will protect against message loss if the network goes down (unless you use UDP). There is also nxlog-processor for non-service mode.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you have example of nxlog conf file for that?